The number of elemements in $\{a\in\mathbb{Z}: |A|\geq4\}\cap\{x\in \mathbb{Z}:x>-10\}$ is equal to

Consider the following set
$A=\{x\in \mathbb{Z} : a^3+a^2|x+a|+|a^2x+1|=1, a\in \mathbb{R}\}$. Then the number of elemements in $\{a\in\mathbb{Z}: |A|\geq4\}\cap\{x\in \mathbb{Z}:x>-10\}$ is equal to

My Approach:
As we want $a^3+a^2|x+a|+|a^2x+1|=1$ to satisfy this equation we must have $x+a\leq 0$ and $a^2x+1\geq 0$.
Also in question asked $|A|\geq 4$ and $x>-10$ so $x$ must belong to interval $(-10,-4]\cup[4,\infty)$
Now solving $a$ for which $a^2x+1\geq 0$
Because $x\in (-10,-4]\cup[4,\infty)\implies a^2x+1\in(-10a^2+1,-4a^2+1]\cup[4a^2+1,\infty)$
We want $a^2x+1\geq 0\implies 4a^2+1\geq0\implies a^2\geq\frac{-1}{4}\implies a\in \mathbb{Z}$
Now solving $a$ for which $x+a\leq 0$
Because $x\in (-10,-4]\cup[4,\infty)\implies -x\in (-\infty,-4]\cup [4,10)$
I am not able to solve this portion of the question and given answer is $8$
Also I am attaching Image of the source question


Why must $x+a\le0$ and $a^2x+1\geq0$?

I don't understand your definition of $A$. Do you mean
$$A={x\in \mathbb{Z} \mid \forall a\in \mathbb{R}, \quad
a^3+a^2|x+a|+|a^2x+1|=1},$$ or
$$\forall a\in \mathbb{R}, \quad
A(a)={x\in \mathbb{Z} \mid
a^3+a^2|x+a|+|a^2x+1|=1},$$ or something else?

@ultralegend5385 otherwise we won't get $1$

@AnneBauval as I can understand it's first definition you wrote

@mathophile: I don't see how. Can you explain a bit?

$A$ would then be independent from $a$, so ${a\in\mathbb{Z}: |A|\geq4}$ would sound awkward. + Same question as @ultralegend5385 + Why "$|A|\geq 4$ and $x>-10$ so $x$ must belong to interval $(-10,-4]\cup[4,\infty)$"? To me, the whole post (question and attempt) is absurd. What is this source?

How "otherwise we won't get 1"? The sign of these two expressions inside absolute value makes no difference in the result.

Does $|A|$ indicate absolute value of all $x$ values present in $A$?

@Gwen I think this question is wrong.

@mathophile Where was it from?

@AnneBauval It was from one of home assignment given in my classroom.

@mathophile : Are you sure that the definition of $A$ is the first one written in Anne Bauval's comment? I think it should be the second one since then we can get the given answer.

@mathlove Can you provide full solution. They did not mention anything so It may be second one. first one was just my assumption.

I also could provid a full solution, but I think we wouldn't do you a favor in doing so right now. Before that, you should:  1) clarify your post (definition of $A$ or rather $A(a)$ if you agree, and meaning of $|A|$, which I think is rather cardinality than aboslute value as you seemed to interpret) 2) present a new attempt to solve your exercise once updated. And maybe 0) Alert your teacher about their meaningless formulation and ask them to reformulate.
